# Can a Square be completely filled by smaller squares when none of the smaller squares have same area?

Tags: puzzle, combinatorial-geometry

Can a Square $S$ be completely filled by smaller squares $S_i$ when area of $S_i \neq S_j$ whenever $i \neq j$?

PS:The image is only meant to clarify the *complete* filling of squares otherwise it includes two squares of same area and a rectangle

[image]

Comment: There is the trivial solution of just the square itself.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible. [The Mathworld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectSquareDissection.html) has more details.

[image]

Regrettably, there is no way to pack squares with sides $1,2,3,\ldots, 24$  into a square of size $70$.

Comment: This is great, Isn't a generalization possible?

Comment: I don't know, but the Mathworld article has lots of references.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but there is some ways with Extremal or Infinite Descent idea in Mathematical Olympiad.

> Source: **Problem-Solving Strategies Part 14_2 Problem 2**:
>   Prove that we can not fill a cube, with smaller different cubes. (No two cubes are equal.)

This can be rejected if we prove that we can not square a square into smaller different squares. Check my post out on https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1522640_strategy_needed